# redux-form: Accessing state and form-values on handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have the following redux-form (6.5.0) source code:

```js
class MyForm extends Component {

 handleSubmit() {
   console.log("Inside the handleSubmit of the MyForm Component where state is accessible", this.state.MyStateElement);
 }

 function render() {
  return (
    <<<< CHOICE 1: >>>> 
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))} >

    <<<< CHOICE 2: >>>> 
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>

    {someFields}
   </form>
  );
 }
}

function submit(values) {
 console.log("submit function outside the MyForm Component where form values are accessible but the State is NOT accessible", values);
 // values correspond to every checkbox, radio button inside MyForm
}
```

There is a MyForm component. It has a redux-form inside. Now there is a handleSubmit() function that is defined inside the react component. There is a submit() function that is defined outside the react component. Now I can enable either the CHOICE 1 or the CHOICE 2 definition for the form tag. If I enable the first one, the handleSubmit inside the react component is called. Here, I am able to access the `this.state` but not able to access the individual fields inside the form (unless I could map each of the fields to a global state manually, which I could not do explicitly for the dozens of Fields that I have). If I enable the CHOICE 2, the values for all the fields are so correctly coming to the `submit` function. But I am not able to access the `this.state` inside the `submit` function.

My question is: Is there a way to get the Field values as well as the `this.state` in a handleSubmit/submit function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution (not sure if this is the best though). I just had to add the values parameter to the `handleSubmit` function. So the updated source will be:

```js
class MyForm extends Component {

 handleSubmit(values) {
   console.log("State:", this.state.MyStateElement);
   console.log("Form values:", values);
 }

 function render() {
  return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))} >
    {someFields}
   </form>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be...

1) When you wrapping your form component with `reduxForm` you specify `onSubmit` option.

```js
class myForm extends React.Component {}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm',
    onSubmit: function(values) { console.log('hello', values) }
})(myForm);
```

2) This function is available inside component as `this.props.handleSubmit` so you still can write your own submit handler and call `this.props.handleSubmit` inside it.

```js
class myForm extends React.Component {
  myOwnSubmitHanlder() {
    console.log('hello', this.state);
    this.props.handleSubmit()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.myOwnSubmitHanlder}></form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there any benefits for this approach ? Are there any guidelines on what actions should be done on which of these functions ? Isn't having a single function not cleaner code ? I am not trying to diss your solution just trying to understand better.

Comment: I don't have clear answers to you questions. I'm not a redux pro, just played around with react-redux a few times. Your solution is also fine, but it's a matter of choice

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will wait till tomorrow and see if there are any better solutions.

Comment: Your solution is clearly recommeded in `redux-form` docs, so probably it's a better option. My solution is just "another one" to consider